# Getting Organization of the User from the Active directory

Tags: c#, asp.net, powershell, active-directory

I'm getting all the OU in the "results" from the Active directory using the below code.

```
 pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
 var command = new Command("Get-OrganizationalUnit");
 pipeline.Commands.Add(command);
 results = pipeline.Invoke();
```

But the real task is to find the OU with users not with computers or some other else. I'm not able to get the solution for this.

Comment: There is no such thing as "ou with users not with computers". There are no limitations to mix objects inside given OU. Also: why would you do it like that instead of using DirectorySearcher?

Comment: He's using a powershell cmdlet to achieve it, isn't he? :-). Still, question is lacking information. Ex. an AD OU can contain both computers and users, so that's no help. Is there a ADUser input or something here ? Btw, you know there is an AD-module, right? `Get-ADOrganizationalUnit` is used there.

Comment: Derp...I'm a little out of it today...

Comment: If using .net isn't it better to use the .Net Native commands? i.e. the Directory Searcher objects as opposed to using PowerShell?

Comment: @HungryHippos Thanks Yaar.... I got the users using directory searcher.